# Simplification of $\sum_{m=0}^\infty \text B_z(m+a,b-m)x^m,\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\text B_z(m+a,b-m)x^m}{m!}$ in terms of Kampé de Fériet function

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions, closed-form-expressions, gamma-function

Here is the goal sum where the [Pochhammer Symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) with the [Incomplete Beta function series](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/06/01/03/01/01/0003/)

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\text B_z(m+a,b-m)x^m}{m!}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^{m+a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1-(b-m))_nz^n x^m}{(m+a+n)m!n!}=\frac{z^a}a\sum_{m,n\ge0}\frac{(a)_{m+n} (b-1)_{m+n}(xz)^mz^n}{(a+1)_{m+n}(b-1)_m m! n!}$$

Now use the [Kampé de Fériet](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/341441364_Novel_reductions_of_Kampe_de_Feriet_function) function also [found on Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KampedeFerietFunction.html):

$$\text F^{p,r,u}_{q,s,v}\left(^{a_1,…,a_p;c_1,…,c_r;f_1,…,f_u}_{b_1,…,b_q;d_1,…,d_s;g_1,…,g_v}\ x,y\right)\mathop=^\text{def}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\prod\limits_{j=1}^p(a_j)_{m+n} \prod\limits_{j=1}^r(c_j)_m \prod\limits_{j=1}^u (f_j)_n x^my^n}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^q (b_j)_{m+n} \prod\limits_{j=1}^s(d_j)_m \prod\limits_{j=1}^v(g_j)_n m!n!}$$

Therefore:

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\text B_z(m+a,b-m)x^m}{m!}\mathop= ^{|z|,-a\not\in\Bbb N}\frac{z^a}a \text F^{2,0,0}_{1,1,0}\left(^{a,b-1;;}_{a+1;b-1;}\ xz,z\right)$$

The second sum of interest is:

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \text B_z(m+a,b-m)x^m\mathop= ^{|z|,-a\not\in\Bbb N}\frac{z^a}a \text F^{2,1,0}_{1,1,0}\left(^{a,b-1;1;}_{a+1;b-1;}\ xz,z\right)$$

Is there a simpler closed form or decomposition formula for this case of the Kampé de Fériet function? A solution verification is also needed, but the derivation should be correct. Please give feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is considered simpler, but still:
\begin{split}
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\text B_z(m+a,b-m)x^m}{m!} &= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m!}\int_0^z y^{m+a-1}(1-y)^{b-m-1}\,{\rm d}y\\
&=\int_0^z y^{a-1}(1-y)^{b-1} e^{\frac{xy}{1-y}}\,{\rm d}y.
\end{split}
Similarly,
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \text B_z(m+a,b-m)x^m =\int_0^z \frac{y^{a-1}(1-y)^b}{1-y-xy}\,{\rm d}y.$$

Comment: (+1) Hello, thanks for your integral representations. It turns out the bottom “simpler” integral can be put into closed form with the [First Appell function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/AppellF1/) and the $\int_0^z y^{a-1}(1-y)^{b-1} e^{\frac{xy}{1-y}}\,{\rm d}y$ has no closed form in terms of simpler functions than the Kampé de Fériet function so far. I will probably accept your answer in a bit. Maybe there is a simpler closed form for the top integral?